# Detect for how long if and else statements were executed

Tags: java, if-statement, time, processing

In processing (which is based on java), the `draw` method is constantly being executed as long as the program is running. I'm trying to measure for how long the condition in the if statement was true. 
I have a if statement:

```
if (matrix [3][5]== 3) {
      System.out.println("Closed");
}
else {
 System.out.println("Opened");
    }
```

The value of `matrix [3][5]`changes dynamically (I use Reactivision, and based on some markers position, this value will change). When I run the program, the condition is false so I'll have:

```
opened
opened
...
opened
```

and then the condition will be true so it will print:

```
closed
closed 
etc
```

Before eventually turning back to opened.
I want to measure for how long the condition was true and printed closed, and when it changes, for how long it stayed opened etc: for each lapse of time it returned opened or closed, I want to know for how long.

I started a timer in my setup:

```
void setup () {
startTime = System.nanoTime();
}
```

that I could end in the if statement:

```
if (matrix [3][5]== 3) {
          System.out.println("Closed");
         long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
         System.out.println("Was opened for"+ estimatedTime);
    }
```

So I would know for how long it's been opened. But how can I make it start again to make it measure now for how long it's closed, then opened etc back and forth ? 
I can't figure this out

Comment: Can the "vote-down" user explain what is wrong?

Comment: Have you found your answer yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a new start time in the else branch. And you should set an extra flag indication the last state.

```
if (matrix [3][5]== 3) {
   System.out.println("Closed");
   if (isOpen)
   {
        isOpen=false;
        System.out.println("Runtime: " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime));
   }
}
else {
   if (!isOpen)
   {
        startTime=System.nanoTime();
        isOpen = true;
        System.out.println("Opened");
   }
}
```

Something this way. The result depends on the switch frequency. "System.nanoTime()" may return the same time for different calls.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. You can use the `nanoTime()` or `millis()` functions to record the start time, and then simply use that same function to record the **current** time. Subtract the start time from the current time to get your **elapsed** time.

Here's an example that keeps track of how much time has elapsed since the user clicked:

```
int start;

void setup(){
  size(200, 100);
  start = millis();
}


void draw(){

  background(0);

  int now = millis();
  int elapsed = now - start;
  text("Elapsed: " + elapsed, 25, 25);
}

void mouseClicked(){
  start = millis();
}
```

Comment: Since the draw method keeps on being executed, the now variable will be updated at every instant so I'm not sure this works

Comment: @MatthiasGrahamSlick Yes, this example updates the now variable every frame, but you can update it whenever you want to store the `elapsed` value. This is just an example.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard Done and done, but no hard feelings! The [tag:processing] tag is hard to miss- and it equally gets applied to questions that have nothing to do with the Processing language! They might as well have named the language "computers", haha!

Answer (score 1):

Try to repeat your *setup()* logic in else:

```
boolean flag = true;// opened is true.

    if (matrix[3][5] == 3) {
        if (flag) {
            long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            System.out.println("Was opened for" + estimatedTime);
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            flag = false;
        }

        System.out.println("Closed");// or place in the nested if to be less verbose.
    } else {
        if (!flag) {
            long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            System.out.println("Was closed for" + estimatedTime);
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
            flag = true;
        }

        System.out.println("Opened");
    }
```

GL!

Comment: The start time is reset on each else call.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep 2 fields in class, where you want to measure a time of opened status as below:

```
private Long startOpenedStatus=null;
private Long endOpenedStatus=null;
private int[][] matrix=new int[5][5]; 



public void yourMethod(){
    //...
    if (matrix [3][5]== 3) {
        stopMeasure();
          System.out.println("Closed");
    }
    else {
        startMeasure();
     System.out.println("Opened");
    } 

    //...
}

/** take time of start opened status, takes only one (first time method fire) in opened session */
private void startMeasure(){
    if(startOpenedStatus==null){
        //reset time of end the opened status
        endOpenedStatus=null;
        startOpenedStatus=new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();//returns actual time in miliseconds for start of opened status 
    }
}

/** take time of end opened status, takes only one time in closed session*/
private void stopMeasure(){
    if(endOpenedStatus==null){
        endOpenedStatus=new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis();//returns actual time in miliseconds for end of opened Status
        long timeInMilis=endOpenedStatus-startOpenedStatus; //this is interwal between end and start of time (in miliseconds)
        System.out.println("opened status was for "+ timeInMilis+" in miliseconds");
        System.out.println("opened status was for "+reaclculateToSeconds(timeInMilis)+" in seconds");
        startOpenedStatus=null;
    }
}

private BigDecimal  reaclculateToSeconds(long timeInMiliseconds){
    BigDecimal timeInSeconds=new BigDecimal(timeInMiliseconds).divide(new BigDecimal(1000), MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    return timeInSeconds.round(new MathContext(3));
}
```

Comment: Why create a new calendar instance each time while System.currentTimeMillis() returns the same value?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to keep track of the current "state" (open/closed) and reset your startTime when the "state" changes. I haven't tried the following but hopefully it starts you off in the right direction.

First you'd have to define a "lastState" String variable (probably same place you define "startTime" and initialize it in your setup. If you know the initial state, set it to that. I just used "NotSet" as an example.

```
void setup () {
  startTime = System.nanoTime();
  lastState = "NotSet";
}
```

Then you would need a method that compare the current state to the last state and output the elapsed time if there is a state change.

```
private static void logElapsed (String currentState) {
    if(!lastState.Equals(currentState)) {
        // state has changed so output the elapsed time and set the lastState to the currentState
        long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        // reset the startTime to keep track of the elapsed time of the new state
        startTime = System.nanoTime();

        // Output how long the last state
        System.out.println("Was " + lastState + " for "+ estimatedTime);

        // reset the lastState to the current state
        lastState = currentState;                   
    } 
}
```

Finally, you would just need to call it from within your if/else block.

```
if (matrix [3][5]== 3) {
  System.out.println("Closed");
  logElapsed("Closed");  
}
else {
  System.out.println("Opened");
  logElapsed("Opened");
}
```